# Quote in HTML attribute destroys layout

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-entities

My site has user generated content. I noticed that if the user has quotes in some text and later I displayed that text in an HTML attribute, the layout would get screwed up in IE.

```
<a href="link.html" title="user "description" of link">Hello</a>
```

However, if I had generated the same anchor with Javascript (Prototype library), the layout would not be screwed up in IE:

```
$$('body').first().appendChild(
 new Element(
  'a', {
   title: 'user "description" of link',
   href: 'link.html'
  }
 ).update('Hello')
);
```

Why is this so? The JS and the plain HTML versions both have the same intended result, but only the JS doesn't screw up IE. What's happening behind the scenes?

---

BTW, I do strip_tags() and clean XSS attacks from all user input, but I don't strip all HTML entities because I use a lot of form text input boxes to display back user generated text. Form elements literally display HTML entities, which looks ugly.

Comment: Is this behavior reproducible on another browser?

Comment: this is not valid markup, ask Dr. Validator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape all output that is user-specified (using entities). The DOM-methods do that automatically.

Comment: Please define the terms "escape" and "entities." Would using a DOM method do the trick?  Do you have to escape every character, or just the quotation marks?

Comment: @Robert Harvey: [escape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence) and [entity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_entity_reference). You'll need to escape all characters that have a special meaning in HTML. And yes, using the DOM-method would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you are processing the user generated content, but you could use a replace function to clean up the input something like `string.replace("\"", "")`

Comment: Duly noted. I was using vb escape for the double quotes. I changed the example, though I am not sure that is correct either.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question: 'Why is it so' is because in your JavaScript example set the title attribute with single quotes. So the double quotes in the user generated string are already escaped.

In you A tag example, single quotes around the text you use in the title attribute may be a way to solve the rendering problem.

**However,** Your HTML attributes should be in double quotes, so you would be better off using entities, as suggested by @elusive in his answer.